# Aligning ToolTip To SelectedItemIndex of Intellisense

Tags: c#, tooltip, intellisense

Here's the Scenario:

I'm working on a code-editor (Winforms) and I use a `RichTextBox` and a component to serve as Intellisense .

when pressing "." in `RichTextBox`, Intellisense will appear and every object inside of it has a different Tooltip .

something like this:
[image]

now for the Tooltip Position was to follow `SelectedIndex` I came up with this code:

```
public void SetToolTip(Intellisense intellisenseitem)
        {
    if (selectedItemIndex == 0)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 1)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 15, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 2)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 30, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 3)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 45, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 4)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 60, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 5)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 75, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 6)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 90, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 7)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 105, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 8)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 120, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 9)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 135, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 10)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 150, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex == 11)
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 165, 3000);
                }
                if (selectedItemIndex >= 12) //still needed to fix
                {
                    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
                    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + 165, 3000);
                }
}
```

Problem was when Intellisense item reaches above 12 (take note that Intellisense has a filter that filters text (`startswith`) that been type in `Richtextbox` like Intellisense in visual studio)
, it will automatically have a scroll (since it reach its max size)
and the problem now was Tooltip will not follow its Selecteditemindex now when
using the scroll .

control intellisense was like a listbox .(since i mention earlier that its a component that i use)

now my question was on how to make tooltip follow always the `SelectedItemIndex` of the intellisense .

Answer (score 3):

if you refactor your code with this, it will make it a lot easier for you.

```
void SetToolTip(Intellisense intellisenseitem)
 {
    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
    toolTip.Show(text, this, Width + 3, SelectedItemIndex + (15 * selectedItemIndex ), 3000);
 }
```

Once the scroll bar start moving you should use the scroll index rather than the Selected Item index. In theory you should not use the Selected Item Index at all, instead you should be using Selected Item position (I am not sure List box expose the Selected Item Position to the public, you may need to dig into the Reflection and get the private field of the selected item position).

**EDIT**

What you need is:

```
void SetToolTip(Intellisense intellisenseitem)
 {
    toolTip.ToolTipTitle = title;
    var x = Width + 3;
    // get the rectangle of the selected item, the X, Y position of the rectangle will be relative to parent list box.
    var rect = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(listBox1.SelectedIndex); 
    var y = listBox1.Location.Y + rect.Y; // Add ListBox Y and the Selected Item Y to get the absolute Y.

    toolTip.Show(text, this, x, y, 3000);
 }
```

Comment: any suggestion sir how can i do the solution for scroll?

Comment: +1 sir if you could help me how to solve the scroll problem ill accept this answer

Comment: the .GetItemRectangle doesnt exist ... same as x and y ... all i saw was the Position.x and Position.y ... applying this when item reaches to no.13 the tooltip remain at +165 which added an improvement ... but when i scrollup or just click selecteditem tooltip still not following ... still thanks for the idea

Comment: Can you post your ListBox code? The System.Windows.Forms.ListBox has GetItemRectangle, if you use System.Windows.Controls.Listbox, then you need to use different techniques.